# TypeScript allows a property to be set but not accessed (index signature)

Tags: typescript

This interface is an example from the TypeScript docs.
The compiler shows an error for `height`, even though it allows me to set it?

```
// Interface taken from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html
interface SquareConfig {
    color?: string;
    width?: number;
    [propName: string]: any;
}

const sq = <SquareConfig>{
    color: 'red',
    width: 7890,
    height: 888
}

console.log(sq.height); // Property 'height' does not exist on type 'SquareConfig'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now the code in the question is valid.

Since TypeScript 2.2, members of a dictionary can be accessed with the syntax: `x.propName`. Here is [the announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/02/22/announcing-typescript-2-2/):

> Before TypeScript 2.2, writing something like `x["propName"]` was the only way you could make use of a string index signature to grab a property. A little surprisingly, writing a property access like `x.propName` wasn’t allowed. This is slightly at odds with the way JavaScript actually works since `x.propName` is semantically the same as `x["propName"]`. There’s a reasonable argument to allow both forms when an index signature is present.
>
> In TypeScript 2.2, we’re doing just that and relaxing the old restriction. What this means is that things like testing properties on a JSON object has become dramatically more ergonomic.

## Original answer (prior to TypeScript 2.2)

The [syntax of indexable types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) is used to define a type for the properties of an object used as a map. For example:

```
interface Colors {
  [propName: string]: string
}
let colors: Colors = /* here, we provide the map */;
colors['blue'].indexOf('#'); // OK, "indexOf" can be used because the type is string
```

It is a way to define the type of properties that are dynamically named with the syntax `obj['propertyName']`. It's not a way to define any static properties, even if JavaScript would allow it:

```
colors.blue // TS Error: Property 'blue' does not exist on type 'Colors'
```

Therefore, the following indexable type, with `any` instead of a true type, is useless:

```
[propName: string]: any;
```

### The specification (prior to TS 2.2)

From [the specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.9.4):

> 3.9.4 Index Signatures
>
> An index signature defines a type constraint for properties in the containing type.
>
> `IndexSignature:
>      [ BindingIdentifier : string ] TypeAnnotation
>      [ BindingIdentifier : number ] TypeAnnotation`
>
> [...]
>
> **Index signatures affect the determination of the type that results from applying a bracket notation property access** to an instance of the containing type, as described in section [4.13](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.13).

Comment: Well in JS, dot and bracket accessors are just syntax alternatives. The distinction you're making implies that this isn't the case in TypeScript, which makes sense, but have you found any documentation to that effect?

Comment: Confusingly, from the docs at that link: '...they also enforce that all properties match their return type. This is because a string index declares that obj.property is also available as obj["property"]'

Comment: @robC I edited to add a quote from the specification. In TS, `obj.property` is also available as `obj["property"]` (because of JS). The opposite is not true in TS (because of static typing).

Answer (score 2):

Personally I can access it : I see the output '888' in my console.

I remove the compilation warning using this syntax:

```
sq['height']
```

Hope it can help.