# Typescript index signature return an array result in index signature is missing

Tags: typescript

I have an JSON like

```
"phone":{
"home":[{"label":"Phone1", "val":"123"},{"label":"Phone1", "val":"123"},{"label":"Phone1", "val":"123"}],
"work":[{"label":"Phone1", "val":"123"}, {"label":"Phone1", "val":"123"}, {"label":"Phone1", "val":"123"}],
"....":[{"label":"Phone1", "val":"123"}]}
```

so there could be more phone objects f.e. emergency phone etc etc but what i know is the value will be an array of label/val objects.

so I created an interfaces

```
export interface Person {
    phone:IHashOfPhones
}

export interface IHashOfPhones {
    [index:string]: Phone[]
}

export interface Phone {
    label: string;
    val:string; 
}
```

however during compilation i have and error like

```
Index signature is missing in type { home : ...
```

if i set `IHashOfPhones` to return `any` everything is ok but i loose the type safety.

in the code i will just loop it, no assignments

Is there a way how to keep the type safety or I am doing something completly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

## With indexable types

From a JSON string:

```
let jsonString: string = `{
  phone: {
    home: [{ label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }],
    work: [{ label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }],
    other: [{ label: "Phone1", val: "123" }]
  }
}`;
let data1: Person = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Or, from a JS object:

```
let data2: Person = <any>{
  phone: {
    home: [{ label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }],
    work: [{ label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }],
    other: [{ label: "Phone1", val: "123" }]
  }
};
```

The [syntax of indexable types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) is a way to define the type of properties that are dynamically named with the syntax `obj['propertyName']`. It's not a way to define any static properties, even if JavaScript would allow it. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765203/typescript-allows-a-property-to-be-set-but-not-accessed-index-signature/39768162#39768162).

## With static properties

The other way is to statically define the available properties:

```
export interface IHashOfPhones { // Replace the other implementation by this one
  home?: Phone[]
  work?: Phone[]
  other?: Phone[]
}
let data3: Person = {
  phone: {
    home: [{ label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }],
    work: [{ label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }, { label: "Phone1", val: "123" }],
    other: [{ label: "Phone1", val: "123" }]
  }
};
```

Comment: i think iam doing the same as you are but in my case returning an array is for some reason not working, damn ....

Comment: No, an object is not a string. Just use the example "from a JS object" with a cast to `<any>`.